# nginx redirect 301 all pages to another domain / homepage add query string

Tags: linux, redirect, nginx, web, http-status-code-301

I ask for help because I have already broken my head, I do not know how to solve the problem ...

I move from one domain to another domain, I want all links  301 redirect to to the new domain, but to the home page  I want to add query string like ?from=example.com (only for homepage).

https://example.com    301 ->  https://newdomain.com/?from=example.com

all other links are just redirect 301 like https://newdomain.com$request_uri;

I tried so, but it does not work

```
    server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;

    location = / {
    return 301 https://newdomain.com/?from=example.com;
    }

    return 301 https://newdomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: what does happen?

Comment: curl -I https://example.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 13 Mar 2018 11:40:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://newdomain.com/

curl -I https://example.com/some-location/test
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 13 Mar 2018 11:40:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://newdomain.com/some-location/test

Comment: curl -I example.com/   ?  BTW, what version of nginx?

Comment: curl -I https://example.com/ 
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently  
Server: nginx  
Date: Tue, 13 Mar 2018 11:50:55 GMT  
Content-Type: text/html  
Content-Length: 178  
Connection: keep-alive  
Location: https://newdomain.com/

Comment: I did ask for "example.com/", not "example.com"

Comment: sorry, how i can format text on comment? nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.12.2 curl -I https://example.com/  
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently  
Server: nginx  
Date: Tue, 13 Mar 2018 11:50:55 GMT  
Content-Type: text/html  
Content-Length: 178  
Connection: keep-alive  
Location: https://newdomain.com/

Comment: No formatting is possible in comments on Stackoverflow sites.  Only in questions and answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your last "return 301" was overruling those inside the location.

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name  example.com www.example.com;

  location = / {
    return 301 https://newdomain.com/?from=example.com;
  }

  location / {
    return 301 https://newdomain.com$request_uri;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm nob to nginx. What is the difference of `= /` and `/` aka what `=` sign means? Thank you.

Comment: "= /"  matches a request for the root, eg "httpl//www.example.com/", "/" matches every request (they all start with "/").